# Putting children inside include tag

Tags: android, android-xml

So according to this - http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html, I can use the include tag to reuse layouts.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:layout_height=”match_parent”
android:background="@color/app_bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

<TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />

...

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to put elements inside an include tag.

For example:

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar">
    <Button/>
</include>
```

If not, how can I get a similar effect.

My goal is to be able to make the include tag the root element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put elements from xml, you must add them in `titlebar.xml` **not** in `<include> </include>`.
otherwise you can add your elements from code :

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.your_title_bar_id);
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(btn );
```